# Unable to install older versions of iOS Simulator from Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode4

I am trying to install older versions of iOS Simulator (specifically iOS 4.3 and 4.0). It takes a long time to download (because its huge) and then terminates the installation saying the package is "untrusted". No clue what to do here. Please help.
Here are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]